# How pass data with @Input more than one nested level component in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

my code structure is like below

```
---ComponentA
------ComponentB
---------ComponentC
```

in `componentA.html` code is like

```
<component-a [title]="abc"></component-a>
```

in `componentB.ts`  i am getting like below

```
  @Input title:string;
```

now i need to get it in `componentC.ts` and i am doing like below

`@Input title:String //in this case it is coming **undefined**`

How will i get it in **componentC**.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `abc` as string then use

```
<component-a title="abc"></component-a>
```

or

```
<component-a [title]="'abc'"></component-a>
```